# Prioritisation of the universal selector (*) in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I was wondering what the prioritisation for the universal selector `*` was in CSS. Is it above or below classes?

Comment: See for yourself https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1501/

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can write a global selector and a class selector and figure it out yourself

Comment: "Priority" is a very vague term. In reality there are many aspects to the cascade. Specificity is just *one* of them. The specificity of the universal selector is zero, but that doesn't take into account 1) competing declarations 2) properties that compute differently based on *other* properties 3) inheritance 4) inline style attributes 5) presentational attributes and 6) !important. You'd do well to narrow down your question, as a general answer to your question is unlikely to solve the actual problem you're facing.

Comment: @BoltClock Agree ... and as you can see in my update (after a chat), there were more to it

Comment: Hello, this morning you asked a question which title was : *text not inheriting  information  from DIV in CSS*. Did you find a solution for it or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has a lower [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than a named one, here showing both class and tag rules

```css
.text {
  color: blue;
}
div {
  color: blue;
}
* {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="text">Test span</span>
<div class="text">Test div</div>
```

---

Updated based on comment

If there were to be child element, they will use global selector rule though, unless one explicit tell them to inherit parent, done in 2:nd and 3:rd div, globally or specific.

```css
.text {
  color: blue;
}
div {
  color: blue;
}
* {
  color: red;
}

div.text.nr2 * {
  color: inherit;
}

div.text.nr3 b {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  Test div
  <span>Test span</span>
  <b>Test bold</b>
</div>

<div class="text nr2">
  Test div
  <span>Test span</span>
  <b>Test bold</b>
</div>

<div class="text nr3">
  Test div
  <span>Test span</span>
  <b>Test bold</b>
</div>
```

Comment: This is strange, because with a bit of code I am using and the universal indicator is prioritised. Does it matter which one goes first?

Comment: @JohnyNich As you can see the global selector `*` in my sample is after, and if they were equal it would override the ones before it, so no, it does not matter, unless you gave it `!important`

Comment: I've tried putting it after but it still does not work.

Comment: @JohnyNich What does not work? .... post the code in a fiddle so I can see

Comment: @JohnyNich The `h` becomes red because no where else it has been given any other color, so what color do you expect them to have?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134834/discussion-between-johnynich-and-lgson).